# Retrieve huge number of records ( 300000 ) using a c# code from a table (Teradata Database)

Tags: c#, java, sql, odbc, teradata

I have a portion of a code where I need to get the data from the table for a particular condition 
( where accountid = '  ' ) . The data retreival is a very slow process . Retreving record it self takes 2 hours . I tried adding cocurrent threads to speed up the process , but did not have much benefit in terms of time .

It would be helpful if some one could suggest me a better and faster way for retreival .

PS : I am making an ODBC connection and then running a query and getting the output of the query .

Comment: check once Is Constraints and Keys are properly defined in your table?

Comment: I wonder what you will do with 300000 records? are you planning to display it to a user?

Comment: 300k records shouldn't be that slow unless you have a terrible line. You might want to show your table structure and/or your code.

Comment: 300k records is not that many. If you have LAN connection to DB, they should load in 1-2 minutes from any DB. Add more details about your query, how many total records are in the DB, are there any indexes, average record size etc?

Comment: Do you have access to the DBQL logs for your query? We need to better understand exactly where your pain point is. What is the time difference between StartTime and FirstStepTime (parsing + workload delay) and the time between FirstStepTime and FirstRespTime (time for Teradata to execute the query). If all of those times are reasonable then you problem is between Teradata and the mid-tier or client.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need an index on accountid.  Is it a primary key?  If not, create an index around that column.

Comment: We don't know how many times he is calling his query etc., just that he's pulling 300k records out of a db.  See the part about concurrent threads?